# How can I add namespace declarations in a SOAPEnvelope

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, ws-security

In my soap application, I'm using apache cxf.

Here's my code which will submit data to the server.

```
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor;

SpringBusFactory bf = new SpringBusFactory();
URL              busFile = Submission.class.getResource(WSSEC_XML);    
File             f = new File(busFile.getPath());

Bus              bus = bf.createBus(busFile.toString());
BusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
BusFactory.setThreadDefaultBus(bus);

DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker coverageChecker = new DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker();

coverageChecker.setSignBody(true);
coverageChecker.setSignTimestamp(true);
coverageChecker.setEncryptBody(true);
coverageChecker.setSignAddressingHeaders(true);

MyClaimservice  service = new MyClaimservice();
Myclaims        port = service.getMyClaimsSoap11();
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);
provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, SOAP_ACTION);

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
client.getInInterceptors().add(new WSS4JInInterceptor(getInProps()));
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JOutInterceptor(getOutProps()));
client.getInInterceptors().add(coverageChecker);

SubmissionResponse response = port.submission(request);
```

My request data is formed like this.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    ....
    ....
    ....
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to add additional namespace to `<soap:Envelope>`. My expected data should be like this,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prefix1="url1" xmlns:prefix2="url2" xmlns:prefix3:"url3">
    ....
    ....
    ....
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried adding those prefixes and namespace urls to `DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker` using Map and XpathExpressions. But seems like it does not made any changes to my request data.

```
Map<String, String> prefixes = new HashMap<String, String>();

prefixes.put("prefix1", "url1");
prefixes.put("prefix2", "url2");
prefixes.put("prefix3", "url3");
prefixes.put("prefix4", "url4");
prefixes.put("prefix5", "url5");

List<XPathExpression> xpaths = Arrays.asList(
        new XPathExpression("//prefix1:Envelope", CoverageType.SIGNED),
        new XPathExpression("//prefix2:Envelope", CoverageType.SIGNED),
        new XPathExpression("//prefix3:Envelope", CoverageType.SIGNED),
        new XPathExpression("//prefix4:Envelope", CoverageType.SIGNED),
        new XPathExpression("//prefix5:Envelope", CoverageType.SIGNED));

DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker coverageChecker = new DefaultCryptoCoverageChecker();

coverageChecker.addPrefixes(prefixes);
coverageChecker.addXPaths(xpaths);

coverageChecker.setSignBody(true);
coverageChecker.setSignTimestamp(true);
coverageChecker.setEncryptBody(true);
coverageChecker.setSignAddressingHeaders(true);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 2:**

I've tried Apache cxf's transformation feature.

```
Map<String, String> outTransformMap = Collections.singletonMap("{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope", "Envelope");
TransformOutInterceptor transformOutInterceptor = new TransformOutInterceptor();
transformOutInterceptor.setOutTransformElements(outTransformMap);
client.getOutInterceptors().add(transformOutInterceptor);
```

According to http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html#TransformationFeature-JAX-WS, above code will remove that specific namespace from `Envelope` node. And I can also confirm it by seeing the `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` is being removed from `<soap:Envelope>`

I tried the reverse of `transformOutInterceptor.setOutTransformElements(outTransformMap);` by replacing it with `transformOutInterceptor.setOutAppendElements(outTransformMap);`, where the `outTransformMap` will now contains `Collections.singletonMap("{url1 (which I need to add)}Envelope", "Envelope");`. But it's not appending it as a new Namespace to `Envelope`. What am I doing wrong here.. Is it really difficult to add additional namespace to `<soap:Envelope>` other than the default namesapce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging on cxf forums, I found the answer.

```
Map<String, String> nsMap = new HashMap<>();

nsMap.put("prefix1", "url1");
nsMap.put("prefix2", "url2");
nsMap.put("prefix3", "url3");
nsMap.put("prefix4", "url4");
nsMap.put("prefix5", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#");

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);   
client.getRequestContext().put("soap.env.ns.map", nsMap);
```

**I would be appreciated if anyone know on how to do the same for `<soap:Header>`**

Comment: Thanks bro... Very useful this. Could you do the same for <soap:Header>?

Answer (score 1):

You can add headers like this:

```
UserCredentials authHeader = new UserCredentials();
    authHeader.setUsername(username);
    authHeader.setPassword(password);
    ArrayList<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>(1);
    try {
        Header soapHeader = new Header(new QName(TQIntegrationV2.TQIntegrationV2Soap.getNamespaceURI(), "UserCredentials"), authHeader, new JAXBDataBinding(UserCredentials.class));
        headers.add(soapHeader);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception trying to serialize header: {}", ex);
    }
    client.getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
```

you can leave setUsername/setPassword if you dont want.

Comment: Glad I can help to find an answer.

Comment: In my SOAP UI, `envelope and Header` were formed as `<soapenv:Envelope and <soapenv:Header` and 'To From Action ReplyTo' were formed as `<wsa:To , <wsa:From , <wsa:Action , <wsa:ReplyTo`. But in my java request, it is formed as `<soap:Envelope and <soap:Header` (no `env` is present after soap) and `<To , <From , <Action , <ReplyTo` (no `wsa:` is present before the nodes). Is there anyway that I can change the node prefix to match the SOAPUI data?